# Cannot solve this SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant seem to work out why:

```
SELECT `Title`.`Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address1`, `Address2`, `Town`.`Town`, `County`.`County`, `PostalCode`, `Phone1`, `Solo` 
FROM `Person` 
JOIN `Title` ON `Person`.`Title` = `Title`.`id` 
JOIN `Town` ON `Person`.`Town` = `Town`.`id` 
JOIN `County` ON `Person`.`County` = `County`.`id` 
WHERE `Person`.`Solo`='1' 
ORDER BY `LastName` ASC;
```

Returns 0 results, (which it shouldn't, there are at least 5 results where `Solo`='1')

And if I modify it, to take out all the JOINS:

```
SELECT `Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address1`, `Address2`, `Town`, `County`, `PostalCode`, `Phone1`, `Solo` 
FROM `Person` 
WHERE `Person`.`Solo`='1' 
ORDER BY `LastName` ASC;
```

I get Results? If I modify it to take out the `WHERE Person.Solo='1'` It gives me results too, but only 2; where surley it should return ALL the rows?  Can someone explain?

:)

note: Solo is a tinyint, it equels either 0 or 1 in all the records!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your joins are strict, it means that if `Person` doesn't have `Title` *or* `Town` *or* `Country` then it wouldn't be returned. You don't get any results even if you remove whole `WHERE` clause.

Try `LEFT JOIN` instead.

This is good explanation of how different type of joins work: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Aah that was it! Thank you for your help, I will read up again on LEFT RIGHT and JOIN ! :)

Comment: @Chud37, you are welcome) I've added link to article about join types.

Answer (score 1):

There are some common conventions, that makes your code more readable to others. First, always use `id` for the (autoincrement) -primary-key. Then use xxxxx_id in related tables. Second, you should use a more precise JOIN-declaration: LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN. Thats more easy to read. Third: Normally there is no need to use ``. In addition to that, you can use a table-alias, to reduce the amound of SQL-code.

```
SELECT ti.title, firstname, lastname, address1, address2, to.town, county.county, postalcode, phone1, solo 
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN title AS ti ON p.title = ti.id 
LEFT JOIN town AS to ON p.town_id = to.id 
LEFT JOIN county AS c ON p.county = c.id 
WHERE p.solo=1
ORDER BY lastname ASC;
```

Just a recommendation...